# Can't start ddp analyzer proxy

Tags: meteor, ddp

I installed DDP analyzer as said here : http://meteorhacks.com/discover-meteor-ddp-in-realtime.html
When I start ddp analyzer proxy terminal gives me : 
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

How to solve this problem? Could anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Node. Meteor comes with its own copy, but ddp-analyser does't use that copy.

You should be able to download it from https://nodejs.org.